# How to let a GridView popup from a TextBox as a Searchfield in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, user-controls

Here, I attached my windows application image. When I press the enter key, the GridView will popup.

Please check the image at https://drive.google.com/open?id=10rVH8KNewOsxp2gIa7bNywVQW3rW_Mfw

I want this type of search view also in ASP.net application.

Please tell me how it is possible to do that.
What I'm intend to do is, when the user presses the enter key while the Focus is inside the TextBox, then the GridView should open in a popup and if the user selects the row, the selected row will return the value of the textbox that is the selected customer name.

what i tried
in .ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLovFilter" runat="server"
ontextchanged="txtLovFilter_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbpop" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>


<!--Model popup extender-->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpLovFilter" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnLovFilter" TargetControlID="lbpop" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnLovFilter" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none">
<div class="dvLovFilter">
<asp:GridView ID="gvLovFilter" runat="server" 
OnRowDataBound="gvLovFilter_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close"/>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

in ascx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                gvLovFilterBind();
            }
        }
        public void gvLovFilterBind()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = DatabaseUntil.ReturnDataSet("exec GetLovQuery '" + _LovFor + "'");
            string sqlqry = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Query"].ToString();
            sqlqry = sqlqry.Replace("<<COMPANYCODE>>", "1");
            sqlqry = sqlqry.Replace("<<PRODUCTCODE>>", "1");
            sqlqry = "Select top 20" + sqlqry;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["Visible"].ToString() == "1" && dr["position"].ToString() == "D")
                {
                    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                    bfield.HeaderText = dr["rd_column_caption"].ToString();
                    bfield.DataField = dr["rd_column_name"].ToString();
                    bfield.HeaderStyle.Width = Convert.ToInt32(dr["rd_column_width"].ToString());
                    bfield.ItemStyle.Width = Convert.ToInt32(dr["rd_column_width"].ToString());
                    gvLovFilter.Columns.Add(bfield);
                }
            }
            gvLovFilter.DataSource = DatabaseUntil.ReturnDataTable(sqlqry);
            gvLovFilter.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gvLovFilter.DataBind();
        }
        private string _LovFor;
        public string LovFor
        {
            get { return _LovFor; }
            set { _LovFor = value; }
        }
```

in aspx

```
<vs:LovFilter ID="LovFilter1" runat="server" Text="" LovFor="Customer"></vs:LovFilter>
```

Comment: Please add some code you tried

Comment: "I want this type of gridview popup search in asp.net" so you mean HTML, CSS and JavaScript? If so, please don't tag your question with C#

Comment: Hello Jeenath, I know your goal, but you have to give us what have you tried.

Comment: i don't how to do this @Znaneswar @ Syafiqur